# What is the best control to use for a single value bar graph (one value from 0 - 10)?

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

I just want to know how can I draw something like a simple bar graph that plots only one value.
I was going to use a Canvas but is there a specific graph control that can be used?

[image]

Comment: It is called "ProgressBar", you can easily find it back in the toolbox.

Comment: I was considering progress bar already, I just wanted to know for sure since its not technically an 'application progress' that I'm tracking

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [`Slider`](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Basic_Slider_control_in_Windows_Phone) control.

```
<Slider HorizontalAlignment="Left"
        VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="369" Minimum="10" Maximum="10" 
        Value="{Binding YourPropertyHere, Mode=OneWay}"
        />
```